# count markers displayed on map after zoom in and out

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google-maps-utility-library-v3.
I am trying to zoom in and zoom out, if the dot is not in screen anymore, I want to see count 0.
But it doesn't work. If I comment out mgr.addMarkers(markers,5); It works.... But it will always be 0 because no maker is managed by the manager.
Could someone tell me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=??????????????&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/src/markermanager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map = null;
  function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.35428, -71.05525),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

    //hard code a marker
    var lat = 42.35428;
    var lng = -71.05525;
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var html = "I am a hard-coded dot";
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png",
        shadow: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/arrowshadow.png"
    });
    var markers = [];
    markers.push(marker);
    var mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
    mgr.addMarkers(markers,5);
    mgr.refresh();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
        var count = mgr.getMarkerCount(zoomLevel);
        document.getElementById("Listing").innerHTML += count + "<BR>";
    });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: No big deal, but just for clarity, you are actually using one of the many v3 utility libraries: [MarkerManager v1.0](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerManager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the MarkerManager before it is fully initialized. Here's an updated section of your code to fix the issue:

```
var markers = [];
markers.push(marker);
var mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mgr, 'loaded', function(){
    mgr.addMarkers(markers, 5);
    mgr.refresh();
});
```

See this example as reference: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/examples.html

Comment: Thanks very much! This works great! I am very new to javascript, could you please drop several words to explain what the execution order is here and what is 'loaded' event of mgr? I appreciate it.

Comment: The marker manager library performs several operations on the map that are only valid after the map has fully initialized. The library writers added the 'loaded' event so that you could ensure that the map was ready to manipulate prior to adding markers.