# Count Number of GMSCircles in View Google Maps SDK...or use MarkerManager Instead? Does this exist for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, zooming, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to count the number of GMSCircles in the users current view in iOS Swift. For example, when the user zooms in or out I want it to count the number of circles currently on the screen. I have something like this right now to append the all my circles to screen...

```
 var circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
 circle.append(GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: 1))
 circle[index].fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.35, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05)
 circle[index].strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
 circle[index].strokeWidth = 10
 circle[index].map = self.mapView;
```

I saw in java that there is a MarkerManager for Markers (which are different than Circles i know) where you can count the number of markers in the view like this:

[count markers displayed on map after zoom in and out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457942/count-markers-displayed-on-map-after-zoom-in-and-out)

but I couldn't find anything like MarkerManager for Swift. Can someone point me in the right direction...I would like to use 'circles'...But i think even in java that may be hard to do. Does the iOS have something like MarkerManager that I can use to count Markers instead of circles? Any help would be really great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what I wanted to do. Using a class level array named longitudeCollection instead of using GMSCircles though

```
    var visibleRegion : GMSVisibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: visibleRegion.nearLeft, coordinate: visibleRegion.farRight)

    var numberOfCirclesInBounds = 0

    for var index = 0; index<=longitudeCollection.count-1; index++ {

        var foo = longitudeCollection[index].coordinateValue
        var bar = latitudeCollection[index].coordinateValue

        var circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(bar, foo);

        if bounds.containsCoordinate(circleCenter) {
            numberOfCirclesInBounds++
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a explicit method for it, but what you can do call `[cameraForBounds][1]` to get the bounding coordinates of your viewport. With that, you can check to see if any of your `circleCenter`s fall within the bounds of the viewport.

Comment: I did not know cameraForBounds existed, I'll check that out, Thanks!